# Add a vhost in chef apache2-windows cookbook

Tags: apache, vagrant, chef-infra, chef-recipe, chef-solo

I'm pretty new to chef. I'm using it to provision a vagrant development environment using the [apache2-windows](https://github.com/chef-windows/apache2-windows) cookbook, which inconveniently has very little by way of documentation. I have managed to get it to install, and even play nicely with [opscodes php](https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/php) cookbook, but I'm struggling to get it to set up a vhost.

So far I have added the vhosts 'extra' to /attributes/default.rb like so:

```
default['apache']['windows']['extras'] = ["vhosts"]
```

That successfully adds a 'vhosts.d' directory to apache root, includes httpd-vhosts.conf in httpd.conf, and adds an entry to httpd-vhosts.conf which includes *.conf in the 'vhosts.d' directory.

Unfortunately I can't quite figure out how to use the virtualhost resource provided with the recipe, which looks like it should be putting my vhosts into the 'vhosts.d' using the /templates/default/virtualhost.conf.erb template.

I have added the following to /recipes/default.rb

```
virtualhost "mysite.localhost" do
  server_aliases ["www.mysite.localhost"]
  docroot "/vagrant"
  action :create
end
```

but it fails, telling me 'No resource or method named 'virtualhost' for 'Chef::Recipe "default"'.

What am I missing? Is there something else I need to do to allow me to use the virtualhost resource in my recipe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's one of the caveat with library cookbooks/LWRP their names are derived from the cookbook name.

Doc is [HERE](http://docs.getchef.com/lwrp_custom.html)

If apache2-windows is not in the runlist you have to define it with `depends 'apache2-windows'` in your cookbook metadata.rb.

But the main problem here is that the virtualhost resource will be named `apache2_windows_virtualhost` due to 2 things:

- The resource is derived from the cookbook name, so it become `cookbook_resource`
- Ruby does not allow `-` in classes names, so they are 'magically' converted to `_` for resources calls.

**tl;dr;** use this

```
apache2_windows_virtualhost "mysite.localhost" do
  server_aliases ["www.mysite.localhost"]
  docroot "/vagrant"
  action :create
end
```

Comment: Worked a treat. Thank you very much - I couldn't find this documented anywhere!

Comment: thanks, I forgot to link to the official documentation, but the part on the class/resource name is kind of hidden.